# How to set background color of list item which is clicked in android?

Tags: android, listview, background, selection

I have created a list view. when i click any item of list i want to set background to it .when i clicks other item background of previous removed and set to other .how can i achieve this. i have tried several ways.I have tried using selector and other ways. 
code snippet is given below:_

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selectedItem" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/GREEN" />
<item
    android:drawable="@color/BLACK" />
```

and code of Activity

```
bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_books);
/*  selectedView = null;
    bookListView.invalidate();*/
    bookListView.setSelector( R.drawable.list_selector);
```

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using for this ListView?

Comment: I am using arrayAdapter<class>.

Comment: apply click event on item, then change color of background layout.

Comment: yes, i am trying this way also but how can i remove color when selects oteher. please give some code snippet .

Comment: I would use a custom adapter but there's probably a way to do something with an onItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // We store the current position of the selected item
                mSelectedItem = position;
                // We refresh a custom adapter
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
```

In the custom adapter override the getView method with:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);

            if (position == mSelectedItem) {
                //Set active style
            }

            return view;
        }
```